# facebook dialog ios for login

Tags: ios, facebook

I have followed the example of Facebook SDK for iOS (Hackbook) and it works well however whenever the person is logging in the app takes take the person to Safari or the Facebook app (if you have it installed on the device). Is there a way I can call the permission without leaving the app.
Thanks

Comment: is it possible to open login dialog for login rather than, login from safari in Hackbook application for iPhone ?

Answer (score 0):

there once was. But facebooks says that you should use SSO (single sign on) with the official facebook app. So even if you'd modify the files of the facebook-ios-sdk, it would probably not work.